# How do I deploy and configure a MariaDB (Mysql) image for remote connection?

Tags: docker, mysql

Specifically: I want to deploy a docker mariadb image to Heroku, that my other heroku app will connect to, in part because I want that skill, in part so I can extend the architecture in the future, and in part because Jaws DB is very limiting and I would like complete control over my own database.

I deployed the mariadb base image to Heroku, after changing the stack from 'heroku-20' to 'container', and the build seem to have gone successfully.

How do I now shell into it, for instance on the CLI or connect to it via my Java app? How do I expose the right endpoint? For example JawsDB produces this string for me to get connection information to the DB they provisioned (I mutated the values for security)

```
mysql://labyddddddfmk:iwqkan6odddddd6j8@uyu7j8yohcwo35j3.cbetdddddwsb.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/j1ad3ddddmm3p1
```

How do I establish the equivalent? It's obviously not a REST API, but if the current Jaws db can live on a different host, why coudln't mine?

If this is hard/not possible, I'd love to know why. The other thought i had was to deploy inside a cluster to Heroku, with each image sharing the cluster's inner network (assuming that is possible on the platform), but I have not looked into that yet. I want the knowledge of how to configure a remote connection across hosts, without having to go the cluster route, even if that is a good idea, if it is at all possible.

I am not finding many good resources for this online. Thanks!

EDIT: Didn't figure out this problem and I'm still interested in the solution out of curiosity, but I found a workaround nonetheless. I provisioned a free database SQL database on a third party website not connected to Heroku. I won't mention the name because I don't want it to seem like I'm promoting but apparently there are many. Pardon me if this is basic knowledge but I didn't realize how decoupled an app and it's database actually are. They can be in different countries on different servers from different providers. This also solved an 'unrelated' issue that I knew was DB related (I could register and login on localhost but not on the server). I don't want to disparage anyone offering free services, but it seems this was a provider error, but this is part of learning Dev-ops. Next step in mastery is generating my own database from scratch, doing what the platforms do -I guess just taking binaries or building them from source, configuring them and deploying them like you would any ol' app.